# Dual-boot Ubuntu 20.04 w/ Mac Pro, grub-install fails, boot-repair fails

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi, mac

Trying to dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 w/ MacOS Catalina 10.15.5.  Made boot USB drive with Etcher, disabled safe booting to get around T2 security, able to boot from drive.  I had previously partitioned my drive with Disk Utility - not exactly positive I did it correctly but this is the result:

[image: this]

MS-DOS(FAT) - I had previously included a swap partition but removed it upon finding out that 20.04 doesn't need one (install didn't work with either).

When trying to install Ubuntu (I tried both from using Try Ubuntu and installing immediately), I get the error

> Executing 'grub-install /dev/nvme0n1p3' failed.  This is a fatal error.

For context, I am choosing the partition I made, with format, as Ext4 Journaling file system, with a mount point of '/.'  Then I choose to install the boot-loader to the same partition.  Out of frustration, I've also tried installing the boot-loader to the SSD and to the EFI partition (I have no idea if this is terrible or not but I've seen suggestions online to do so). I've gone through some of the suggestions online, including connecting to internet and installing with updates, and trying to repair with boot-repair (this failed, my error pastebin boot-repair generated is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xsj2y43m8y/)).

No matter what I've tried so far, I'm unable to get past grub-install.  Does anyone have a suggestion to help me?

Comment: To be clear, installing to /dev/nvme0n1/ which is just the drive (often suggested online) yields the same error, as does /dev/nvme0n1p1, which is the OSX EFI partition.